# Deleting Bottom and Top node in a LinkedList

Tags: c++, function, linked-list

Im sitting here in a library and i came up with two functions from the top of my head. A removefrombottom function and a removefromtop function that remove the bottom and top node of a linked list. Im wondering if this code would work or if my logic is incorrect. Any suggestions if im wrong would be appreciated. Heres what i came up with

```
void removefrombottom()
{
  StringListNode *curr = pBottom;
  pBottom = pBottom->pPrev;
  delete curr;
}

void removefromtop()
{
  StringListNode *curr = pTop;
  pTop = pTop->pNext;
  delete curr;
}
```

Would these actually delete the Head and tail of a linked list?

Comment: You can test with web-based compiler like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: @John Will try that, but by simply viewing this in your opinion; Would this seem to work?

Comment: Sure, but it's not a useful question. If there _are_ bugs, they're in the stuff you're not showing, so this is just a pseudo-code-review.

Comment: @Useless All im asking is if the logic seems correct.

Comment: And I'm saying it _seems_ correct, but that doesn't mean it _is_. Specifically there are _potential_ bugs with dangling pointers (`pTop->pPrev` is invalid, etc.) but I can't tell if they're important from this snippet.

Comment: The logic is not correct. You need to write test cases, like "one element list".

Comment: @Useless You are absolutely correct, however Im just assuming pTop and pBottom are pointers to the head and tail. Thank you though! And Mr K, i understand that but lets assume these are functions that are only called when the list has 10 or more items.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing a code, which should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must check if the list is empty before remove any element. And also actualize the pTop and pBottom pointers when the list have only one element.

```
void removefrombottom()
{
   if(pBottom != NULL){ //OR if(size > 0){
       StringListNode *curr = pBottom;
       pBottom = pBottom->pPrev;
       if(curr == pTop) pTop = NULL;
       delete curr;
       //--size;
   }
}

void removefromtop()
{
   if(pTop != NULL){ //OR if(size > 0){
       StringListNode *curr = pTop;
       pTop = pTop->pNext;
       if(curr == pBottom) pBottom = NULL;
       delete curr;
       //--size;
   }
}
```

Comment: Im simply assuming these are functions called when the list is filled with alot of items. However you are absolutely correct. Thank you for your suggestions!